# Updating entity with One to One relationship using Spring Data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an issue when updating entity with OneToOne relationship, it creates record instead of updating the existing one. Below are the sample entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "crm", name = "persons")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "crm", name = "employees")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId //Use the person PK id value as Employee PK id
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
}
```

I am using the PagingAndSortingRepository of Spring Data. Below is the service layer to update the entity.

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public EmployeeResponse updateEmployee(Employee aEmployee) {
        EmployeeResponse response = new EmployeeResponse();

        try {
            Optional<Employee> probableEmployee = employeeRepository.findById(aEmployee.getId());
            if (!probableEmployee.isPresent()) {
                throw new RecordNotFoundException(String.format(MessageConstants.EMPLOYEE_ID_NOT_FOUND, aEmployee.getId()));
            }

            Employee existingEmployeeToUpdate = probableEmployee.get();
            EmployeeEntityHelper.updateExistingEntity(aEmployee, existingEmployeeToUpdate);

            existingEmployeeToUpdate = employeeRepository.save(existingEmployeeToUpdate);
            response.setSuccessfulResponse(existingEmployeeToUpdate);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
            response.setErrorAttributes(false, ReturnCode.FAILED.getCode(), ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return response;
    }
```

The EmployeeEntityHelper.updateExistingEntity(source, target) will simply copy all properties of entities from source to target.

The save() method will generate an insert for Person even if I am explicitly passing the id existing in DB. But for employee it will generate an update which is expected.

Below is the updateExistingEntity() method:

```
public static void updateExistingEntity(Employee source, Employee target) {
    copyProperties(source, target, Arrays,asList("person", "employeeNumber", "hiredDate", "birthDate"));
}

private static void copyProperties(Object aSource, Object aTarget, Iterable<String> aProperties) {
        BeanWrapper sourceWrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(aSource);
        BeanWrapper targetWrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(aTarget);
        aProperties.forEach(p ->
            targetWrapper.setPropertyValue(p, sourceWrapper.getPropertyValue(p))
        );
    }
```

Comment: Post code on updateExistingEntity, probably that is the issue.

Comment: @JonathanJohx, please see updated above

Comment: When debugging you checked before is saved the ID is included? Right?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly, but when creating a new record its fine employee will be associated according to the person id. During update, the Id for employee and associated person object is supplied.

Comment: Okay so you need to put 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  in order to MERGE, that contains ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a new INSERT instead of UPDATEs could be due to:

Either entity passed to save has no ID set, thus persist is called under the hood
Or entity with given ID is not present in the database thus merge fails (and maybe it is persisted as a fallback, dunno)
Check if entities have set ID field.

Comment: Like I said above Id are passed as part of the request and the value is currently existing in the the database. By the way welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

In your model , override equal/hash-code and just chek the id parameter
maybe it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is already fixed, somehow the copyproperties logic is not right in the sense that I am updating/setting the person also.